# How do I compute missing data (zeros, nulls, empty spaces) for each value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, percentage, zero

I have a table with two columns col1 and col2. I am trying to compute the percentage of the columns that are null, empty space, or zero for all codes (code1, code2, code3, code4 ...)
For the table below:

| codes | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| code1 | NULL | 0 |
| code2 | 3 | 1 |
| code2 | 3 | 1 |
| code2 |  |  |
| code1 | NULL | NULL |
| code1 | 4 | 1 |

I want a summary table like below:

| codes | total_count | Missing_values | Missing_Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| code1 | 3 | 2 | 66.67 |
| code2 | 3 | 1 | 33.33 |

I tried the code below but got stuck

```
;WITH allcount AS(
SELECT COUNT(*) Total FROM (
SELECT ft.Codes, Description, col1, col2 FROM data1 d1
)A
),baddata AS(
SELECT f1.Code, COUNT(*) BadCount FROM (
SELECT f1.Codes, Description, col1, col2 FROM data1 d1
)B
WHERE (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL) OR (col1 = ' ' AND col2 = ' ') OR (col1 = '0' OR col2 = 
'0')
GROUP BY f1.ReadCode
)
SELECT ReadCode, Total AS total_count, BadCount as Missing_values,  100*(BadCount/Total) as 
Missing_Percent
FROM allcount, baddata
```

I am not exactly sure how to put the whole thing together, please help me

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you just need some conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT Codes,
       COUNT(Codes) AS TotalCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN NULLIF(Col1,'') IS NULL OR NULLIF(Col2,'') IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS MissingValues,
       AVG(CASE WHEN NULLIF(Col1,'') IS NULL OR NULLIF(Col2,'') IS NULL THEN 1. ELSE 0. END) AS MissingPercent
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Codes;
```